# WebApi OData Delete routing convention

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes, odata

I have a MVVM project. 
For the model I use a EF6.0.0 code first and WebApi.

In general everything works fine but for one thing.

When I do a delete the following URL is composed

http://localhost:50346/Recruiters/Addresses(guid'5d778c9d-56b2-449b-b655-22489e01636d')/CIP.Models.Domain.Addresses

and this results in a 404 error.

So I've created an routing convention like this:

```
using Microsoft.Data.Edm;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Routing;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Routing.Conventions;

namespace CIP
{
    public class AddressesRoutingConvention : EntitySetRoutingConvention
{
    public override string SelectAction(ODataPath odataPath, HttpControllerContext controllerContext, ILookup<string, HttpActionDescriptor> actionMap)
    {
        if (odataPath.PathTemplate == "~/entityset/key/cast")
        {
            HttpMethod httpMethod = controllerContext.Request.Method;
            string httpMethodName;

            switch (httpMethod.ToString().ToUpperInvariant())
            { 
                case "DELETE":
                    httpMethodName = "Delete";
                    break;
                default:
                    return null;
            }

            Contract.Assert(httpMethodName != null);

            IEdmEntityType entityType = odataPath.EdmType as IEdmEntityType;

            string actionName = httpMethodName + entityType.Name;                    

            if (actionName != null)
            {
                KeyValuePathSegment keyValueSegment = odataPath.Segments[1] as KeyValuePathSegment;
                controllerContext.RouteData.Values[ODataRouteConstants.Key] = keyValueSegment.Value;
                return actionName;
            }
        }
        // Not a match
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

and added this route

```
var conventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault();
conventions.Insert(0, new AddressesRoutingConvention());

config.Routes.MapODataRoute("Addresses", "Addresses", addressesBuilder.GetEdmModel(), new DefaultODataPathHandler(), conventions);`
```

And in the controller

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteAddresses([FromODataUri] Guid key)
{
    Addresses addresses = await db.Addresses.FindAsync(key);
    if (addresses == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    db.Addresses.Remove(addresses);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

But still I get the 404 error.

I tried testing it from SOAPUI with the same result.

Am I missing something?

Kind regards

Jeroen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few small errors aside the code is ok.

It turns out the problem was in my web.config.
After adding below configuration to it, everything works, even breakpoints:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="/*" 
          verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
      preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Jeroen

Answer (score 0):

Jeroen

I think What you have done can work.

However, your below request Uri is not right based on your OData route setting:

```
http://localhost:50346/Recruiters/Addresses(guid'5d778c9d-56b2-449b-b655-22489e01636d')/CIP.Models.Domain.Addresses
```

Because your OData route setting is:

```
config.Routes.MapODataRoute("Addresses", "Addresses", addressesBuilder.GetEdmModel(), ...
```

So, your request Uri should be:

```
http://localhost:50346/Addresses/Addresses(guid'5d778c9d-56b2-449b-b655-22489e01636d')/CIP.Models.Domain.Addresses
```

Why do you write **"Recruiters"** ?

Here's my debug information using all your sample codes:
[image]

### Besides, Why do you issue a **Delete** request on a cast Uri? It seems the last type case segment (that is: CIP.Models.Domain.Addresses) is not necessary?

You can refer to *Delete an Entity* section from [OData Spec](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/odata-version-3-0-core-protocol). If you find any issue for Web API OData, you can directly file an issue on [WebApi OData On Github](https://github.com/OData/WebApi).
Thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello Sam Xu,thanks for your answer . This URI is generated by my program, I did not build up myself in anayway. I see the error with Recruiters vs Addresses, so Adding the routing convention to the recruiters route maybe the solution? It doesn't do the trick. I also see some breakpoint in your example, could you tell me ho you managed that. I can set them but I never seem to hit them. How did you do your test? Kind regard Jeroen